# Change audio output depending on monitor application is run in

Tags: audio, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, sound-card

This type of questions has been asked, but did not find solution to my current setup (setup with soundcard).

- I have Xonar DGX sound card, and Nvidia Graphics card.
- I have connected TV to my graphics card HDMI.
- I have connected my pc monitor to my graphics card DVI.
- I have PC speakers connected to soundcard.
- I have Windows 8.1.

Currently all sound is played through PC speakers. The TV shows up in device playback settings and the test sound works.

How to make it automatically play sound over HDMI if application runs on TV? So I hear sound from my TV if TV screen is used for the application. And if the application is run on my PC monitor, it would play sound to my pc speakers?

EDIT:
I don't know the details but I know that in Windows 7 if I connected my laptop to TV with HDMI, it automatically used TV speakers, if I moved for example chrome window to TV monitor that played youtube. And if I moved it back to laptop it played on laptop speakers. I can't get the same behavior with this setup.

Comment: That question does not use sound card

Comment: @Pehmolelu - Does not matter in this case.  A sound card is considered a sound device to Windows.